# Pre-select items from a nested list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, jquery-events

I'm trying to have items in two similar fields (language and deliverables) pre-selected.

```
<div class="fields-wrapper">
  <div class="language-field">
    <ul>
        <li value="1">EN</li>
        <li value="2">ES</li>
        <li value="3">NL</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="deliverables-field">
    <ul>
        <li value="1">A</li>
        <li value="2">B</li>
        <li value="3">C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my Javascript, I'm trying the below two ways to have the respective items selected, but to no avail.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".language-field ul li").val(["1"]).addClass('selected');
  $(".deliverables-field ul li").eq(0).addClass('selected');
 });
```

Comment: One thing I would recommend, since you're using jQuery, is to use $(function() {}), rather than $(document).ready(function() {})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) here. [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is used to get/set the value of an input field.

In your case since you are dealing with `li` the `value` is an attribute of the element.

```
$(function(){
    $('.language-field ul li[value="1"]').addClass('selected');
    $(".deliverables-field ul li").eq(0).addClass('selected');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jceyP/1/)

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense, so in my case at least deliverable item A should've been selected. I tried 
$('.language-field ul li[value="1"]').addClass('selected');
$('.deliverables-field ul li[value="1"]').addClass('selected');
and it's not working. Arrgh!
Just can't get my head around this.

Comment: @Kédar can you check the demo fiddle I created, It is working fine

Comment: Yes, I did, thanks. And it makes perfect sense. I can't seem to put my finger on why my code won't select the item.

Comment: @Kédar how is the html element created? is it present when the page is loaded / is it loaded via ajax

Comment: @Kédar and easy test is to add `alert($(".deliverables-field").length)` before `$('.language-field ul li[value="1"]').addClass('selected');` and see the result

Comment: that is the problem, you need to execute this script once the elements are loaded. Can you share how the html is loaded

Comment: Super Arun. Thanks for the tip about checking the loading sequence. 
Now, I've put this script separately under 
'$(window).bind("load", function() { //code });'

Works now! Phew ;)

Comment: @Kédar I don't think that is the best way to do it, we can suggest a better way if you can show how the html is loaded.